# Entity Framework circular dependency for last entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Please consider the following entities

```
public class What {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
    public int? LastTrackId { get; set; }]
    public Track LastTrack { get; set; }
}

public class Track {
    public Track(string what, DateTime dt, TrackThatGeoposition pos) {
        What = new What { Name = what, LastTrack = this };
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int WhatId { get; set; }
    public What What { get; set; }
}
```

I use the following to configure the entities:

```
builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
builder.HasMany(x => x.Tracks).
    WithOne(y => y.What).HasForeignKey(y => y.WhatId);
builder.Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(100);
builder.HasOne(x => x.LastTrack).
    WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.LastTrackId);
```

Has you can see there is a wanted circular reference:

```
What.LastTrack <-> Track.What
```

when I try to add a `Track` to the context (on `SaveChanges` in fact):

```
Track t = new Track("truc", Datetime.Now, pos);
ctx.Tracks.Add(t);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

I get the following error:

> Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved: ''What' {'LastTrackId'} -> 'Track' {'Id'}, 'Track' {'WhatId'} -> 'What' {'Id'}'.

I would like to say... yes, I know but...

Is such a configuration doable with EF Core ?

Comment: Please show the code that causes the error. This is probably a chicken-and-egg problem (two new objects requiring each other's foreign keys).

Comment: @GertArnold this is exactly that. Right now I solve it by two commits. I'm afraid I didn't keep the exact old code.

Comment: You do need two commits, no alternative. You may want to wrap them in a `TransactionScope`.

Comment: @GertArnold that allows the rollback of the two commits ?

Comment: Yep, that's what `TransactionScope` is commonly used for.

Comment: @GertArnold if you write an answer I'll mark it. Thank you

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is what I like to call the *favored child* problem: a parent has multiple children, but one of them is extra special. This causes problems in real life... and in data processing.

In your class model, `What` (is that a sensible name, by the way?) has `Tracks` as children, but one of these, `LastTrack` is the special child to which `What` keeps a reference.

When both `What` and `Track`s are created in one transaction, EF will try to use the generated `What.Id` to insert the new `Track`s with `WhatId`. But before it can save `What` it needs the generated Id of the last `Track`. Since SQL databases can't insert records simultaneously, this circular reference can't be established in one isolated transaction.

You need one transaction to save `What` and its `Track`s and a subsequent transaction to set `What.LastTrackId`.

To do this in one database transaction you can wrap the code in a [`TransactionScope`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using(var ts = new TransactionScope())
{
    // do the stuff
    ts.Complete();
}
```

If an exception occurs, `ts.Complete();` won't happen and a rollback will occur when the `TransactionScope` is disposed.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, but i solved it differently.

In my case, it was about a list of status and a reference to the last status. So with the following case :

```
public class What {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Status> StatusList { get; set; }
    public int? LastStatusId { get; set; }
    public Status LastStatus { get; set; }

    public void AddStatus(Status s)
    {
        StatusList.Add(s);
        LastStatus = s;
    }
}

public class Status{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int WhatId { get; set; }
    public What What { get; set; }
}
```

In my program, i changed my code to use StatusList as an history that doesn't include the lastStatus, so :

```
public class What {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Status> StatusHistory { get; set; }
    public int? LastStatusId { get; set; }
    public Status LastStatus { get; set; }

    public void AddStatus(Status s)
    {
        if(LastStatus) StatusList.Add(LastStatus);
        LastStatus = s;
    }

    public List<Status> GetStatusList(Status s) // If needed, a method, not a property because i got an error with lazyLoading
    {
        return new List<Status>(StatusHistory) { LastStatus}; // List of all status (history + last)
    }
}

public class Status{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? WhatId { get; set; }
    public What What { get; set; }
}
```

and don't forget to put in your context `IsRequired(false)` on the foreignKey :

```
builder.HasMany(x => x.Status).
    WithOne(y => y.What).HasForeignKey(y => y.WhatId).IsRequired(false);
```

Like this, no more circular reference.